# How can I serialize properties as json object?

Tags: json, spring-boot, serialization, jackson2

How can I serialize  following generic response using jackson??

```
public class GenericResponse{
    private String resource;
    private Integer status;
    private ErrorInfo response;
    //setters and getters
}

public class ErrorInfo {
    private String errorCode;
    private String errorDetails;
    @JsonUnwrapped
    private ErrorFactory errorFactory;
    //setters and getters
}
```

expected output:

```
{
    "resource": "xxxxxx",
    "status": xxxxx,
    "response": {
        "error-info": {
            "errorCode": "xxxxxx",
            "errorDetails": "xxxxx"
            }
    }
}
```

How can i get this using jackson???

If i set wrap_root_value to true then it is serializing in below format....

```
{
    "GenericResponse": {
        "resource": "xxxxxx",
        "status": xxxxxxxxx,
        "response": {
            "errorCode": "xxxxxxxxx",
            "errorDetails": "xxxxxxxxxxx"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You mention it does this whe wrap_root_value is true what happens when it's false?

Comment: your expected output is an invalid JSON. Why do you need it in that form?

Comment: @Zergled by default that property will be false.
{   
   "resource": "xxxxxx",
    "status": xxxxx,
    "response": {
          "errorCode": "xxxxxx",
          "errorDetails": "xxxxx"
        }
}

Comment: @Selindek Soory its a typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to get this by using `@JsonTypeInfo` and `@JsonTypeName` annotations.

```
public class GenericResponse{
private String resource;
private Integer status;
@JsonTypeInfo( use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT)
private ErrorInfo response;
//setters and getters
}

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonTypeName("error-info")
public class ErrorInfo {
private String errorCode;
private String errorDetails;
@JsonUnwrapped
private ErrorFactory errorFactory;
}
```